# Kotlin to achieve multithread request hedging?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor, kotlin-coroutines

Spring's reactor has an interesting feature : **Hedging** . It means spawning many requests and get the first returned result , and automatically clean other contexts. [Josh Long](https://twitter.com/starbuxman) recently has been actively promoting this feature. Googling [Spring reactor hedging](https://www.google.com.tw/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNTRWX4HADGcXYfexzdspac-Gltgiw:1573061757300&source=hp&ei=fQTDXZyPD6iUmAWH-K3ICw&q=spring+reactor+hedging&oq=spring+reactor+hedging&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39.647.647..851...0.0..0.110.110.0j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.LRXcjjWroT8&ved=0ahUKEwjcwYDaj9blAhUoCqYKHQd8C7kQ4dUDCAY&uact=5) shows relative results. If anybody is curious , [here](https://github.com/spring-tips/hedging/blob/master/client/src/main/java/com/example/client/ClientApplication.java#L77) is the sample code . In short , `Flux.first()` simplifies all the underlaying hassles , which is very impressive.

I wonder how this can be achieved with Kotlin's coroutine and multithread , (and maybe with `Flow` or `Channel` ) . I thought of a simple scenario : One service accepts longUrl and spawns the longUrl to many URL shorten service ( such as IsGd , TinyUrl ...) , and returns the first returned URL ... (and terminates / cleans other thread / coroutine resources)

There is an interface `UrlShorter` that defines this work :

```
interface UrlShorter {
  fun getShortUrl(longUrl: String): String?
}
```

And there are three implementations , one for [is.gd](https://is.gd) ,  another for [tinyUrl](https://tinyurl.com) , and the third is a Dumb implementation that blocks 10 seconds and return null :

```
class IsgdImpl : UrlShorter {
  override fun getShortUrl(longUrl: String): String? {
    logger.info("running : {}", Thread.currentThread().name)
    // isGd api url blocked by SO , it sucks . see the underlaying gist for full code
    val url = "https://is.gd/_create.php?format=simple&url=%s".format(URLEncoder.encode(longUrl, "UTF-8"))
    return Request.Get(url).execute().returnContent().asString().also {
      logger.info("returning {}", it)
    }
  }
}

class TinyImpl : UrlShorter {
  override fun getShortUrl(longUrl: String): String? {
    logger.info("running : {}", Thread.currentThread().name)
    val url = "http://tinyurl.com/_api-create.php?url=$longUrl" // sorry the URL is blocked by stackoverflow , see the underlaying gist for full code
    return Request.Get(url).execute().returnContent().asString().also {
      logger.info("returning {}", it)
    }
  }
}

class DumbImpl : UrlShorter {
  override fun getShortUrl(longUrl: String): String? {
    logger.info("running : {}", Thread.currentThread().name)
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10)
    return null
  }
}
```

And there is a `UrlShorterService` that takes all the `UrlShorter` implementations , and try to spawn coroutines and get the first result .

Here is what I've thought of :

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@FlowPreview
class UrlShorterService(private val impls: List<UrlShorter>) {


  private val es: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(impls.size)
  private val esDispatcher = es.asCoroutineDispatcher()

  suspend fun getShortUrl(longUrl: String): String {
    return method1(longUrl) // there are other methods , with different ways...
  }

  private inline fun <T, R : Any> Iterable<T>.firstNotNullResult(transform: (T) -> R?): R? {
    for (element in this) {
      val result = transform(element)
      if (result != null) return result
    }
    return null
  }
```

The client side is simple too :

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@FlowPreview
class UrlShorterServiceTest {

  @Test
  fun testHedging() {
    val impls = listOf(DumbImpl(), IsgdImpl(), TinyImpl()) // Dumb first
    val service = UrlShorterService(impls)
    runBlocking {
      service.getShortUrl("https://www.google.com").also {
        logger.info("result = {}", it)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice I put the `DumbImpl` first , because I hope it may spawn first and blocking in its thread. And other two implementations can get result.

OK , here is the problem , how to achieve hedging in kotlin ? I try the following methods :

```
  private suspend fun method1(longUrl: String): String {
    return impls.asSequence().asFlow().flatMapMerge(impls.size) { impl ->
      flow {
        impl.getShortUrl(longUrl)?.also {
          emit(it)
        }
      }.flowOn(esDispatcher)
    }.first()
      .also { esDispatcher.cancelChildren() } // doesn't impact the result
  }
```

I hope `method1` should work , but it totally executes 10 seconds :

```
00:56:09,253 INFO  TinyImpl - running : pool-1-thread-3
00:56:09,254 INFO  DumbImpl - running : pool-1-thread-1
00:56:09,253 INFO  IsgdImpl - running : pool-1-thread-2
00:56:11,150 INFO  TinyImpl - returning // tiny url blocked by SO , it sucks
00:56:13,604 INFO  IsgdImpl - returning // idGd url blocked by SO , it sucks
00:56:19,261 INFO  UrlShorterServiceTest$testHedging$1 - result = // tiny url blocked by SO , it sucks
```

Then , I thought other method2 , method3 , method4 , method5 ... but all not work :

```
  /**
   * 00:54:29,035 INFO  IsgdImpl - running : pool-1-thread-3
   * 00:54:29,036 INFO  DumbImpl - running : pool-1-thread-2
   * 00:54:29,035 INFO  TinyImpl - running : pool-1-thread-1
   * 00:54:30,228 INFO  TinyImpl - returning // tiny url blocked by SO , it sucks
   * 00:54:30,797 INFO  IsgdImpl - returning // idGd url blocked by SO , it sucks
   * 00:54:39,046 INFO  UrlShorterServiceTest$testHedging$1 - result = // idGd url blocked by SO , it sucks
   */
  private suspend fun method2(longUrl: String): String {
    return withContext(esDispatcher) {
      impls.map { impl ->
        async(esDispatcher) {
          impl.getShortUrl(longUrl)
        }
      }.firstNotNullResult { it.await() } ?: longUrl
    }
  }
```

```
  /**
   * 00:52:30,681 INFO  IsgdImpl - running : pool-1-thread-2
   * 00:52:30,682 INFO  DumbImpl - running : pool-1-thread-1
   * 00:52:30,681 INFO  TinyImpl - running : pool-1-thread-3
   * 00:52:31,838 INFO  TinyImpl - returning // tiny url blocked by SO , it sucks
   * 00:52:33,721 INFO  IsgdImpl - returning // idGd url blocked by SO , it sucks
   * 00:52:40,691 INFO  UrlShorterServiceTest$testHedging$1 - result = // idGd url blocked by SO , it sucks
   */
  private suspend fun method3(longUrl: String): String {
    return coroutineScope {
      impls.map { impl ->
        async(esDispatcher) {
          impl.getShortUrl(longUrl)
        }
      }.firstNotNullResult { it.await() } ?: longUrl
    }
  }
```

```
  /**
   * 01:58:56,930 INFO  TinyImpl - running : pool-1-thread-1
   * 01:58:56,933 INFO  DumbImpl - running : pool-1-thread-2
   * 01:58:56,930 INFO  IsgdImpl - running : pool-1-thread-3
   * 01:58:58,411 INFO  TinyImpl - returning // tiny url blocked by SO , it sucks
   * 01:58:59,026 INFO  IsgdImpl - returning // idGd url blocked by SO , it sucks
   * 01:59:06,942 INFO  UrlShorterServiceTest$testHedging$1 - result =  // idGd url blocked by SO , it sucks
   */
  private suspend fun method4(longUrl: String): String {
    return withContext(esDispatcher) {
      impls.map { impl ->
        async {
          impl.getShortUrl(longUrl)
        }
      }.firstNotNullResult { it.await() } ?: longUrl
    }
  }
```

I am not familiar with `Channel` , sorry for the exception ↓

```
  /**
   * 01:29:44,460 INFO  UrlShorterService$method5$2 - channel closed
   * 01:29:44,461 INFO  DumbImpl - running : pool-1-thread-2
   * 01:29:44,460 INFO  IsgdImpl - running : pool-1-thread-3
   * 01:29:44,466 INFO  TinyImpl - running : pool-1-thread-1
   * 01:29:45,765 INFO  TinyImpl - returning // tiny url blocked by SO , it sucks
   * 01:29:46,339 INFO  IsgdImpl - returning // idGd url blocked by SO , it sucks
   *
   * kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ClosedSendChannelException: Channel was closed
   *
   */
  private suspend fun method5(longUrl: String): String {
    val channel = Channel<String>()

    withContext(esDispatcher) {
      impls.forEach { impl ->
        launch {
          impl.getShortUrl(longUrl)?.also {
            channel.send(it)
          }
        }
      }
      channel.close()
      logger.info("channel closed")
    }

    return channel.consumeAsFlow().first()
  }
```

OK , I don't know if there are any other ways ... but all above are not working... All blocks at least 10 seconds ( blocked by `DumbImpl`) .

The whole source code can be found on [github gist](https://gist.github.com/smallufo/8bcaa1082f0b4b88e045237f494e975e) .

How can hedging be achieved in kotlin ? By `Deferred` or `Flow` or `Channel` or any other better ideas ? Thank you.

After submitting the question , I found all tinyurl , isGd url are blocked by SO . It really sucks !

Comment: You specifically created a fetching method that is non-cancellable for its entire duration. Is that what a real method would do? If so, then you must leak them and not enforce the structured concurrency discipline. Let them take their time in the background. But i really don't know if that's a smart design.

Comment: So , in your opinion , `interface UrlShorter {
  fun getShortUrl(longUrl: String): String?
}` is problematic ?  My initial thought is that , it is just a blocking method , each implementation doesn't need to know it will be invoked by blocking or running inside a suspend function. If error occurs inside (timeout or API invoking ...)  , it just catch Exception and return null (code emitted for brevity) . If the design is not good , how to re-design it ? Thanks.

Comment: If you're working with blocking calls then coroutines don't provide much value anyway. You can solve the same thing with old-school Java executors. But, you still _can_ do it with coroutines, if you ensure you don't wait for the coroutine scope to complete.

Comment: So , if `UrlShorter` defines `suspend fun getShortUrl(longUrl : String) : String?` , how does such architecture be re-designed , without leaky ? i'll be very appreciated if you provide a simple code.

Comment: Just making it `suspend fun` doesn't help, you have to make suspending calls inside it. If that is available to you (if you're just making network requests), then this can be solved properly. In that case one of your solutions may start working as well. I started sketching out a solution as well, I'll write an answer if I get anything good out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actual work you want to do in parallel consists of network fetches, you should choose an async networking library so you can properly use non-blocking coroutines with it. For example, as of version 11 the JDK provides an async HTTP client which you can use as follows:

```
val httpClient: HttpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient()

suspend fun httpGet(url: String): String = httpClient
        .sendAsync(
                HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(url)).build(),
                BodyHandlers.ofString())
        .await()
        .body()
```

Here's a function that accomplishes request hedging given a suspendable implementation like above:

```
class UrlShortenerService(
        private val impls: List<UrlShortener>
) {
    suspend fun getShortUrl(longUrl: String): String? = impls
            .asFlow()
            .flatMapMerge(impls.size) { impl ->
                flow<String?> {
                    try {
                        impl.getShortUrl(longUrl)?.also { emit(it) }
                    }
                    catch (e: Exception) { 
                        // maybe log it, but don't let it propagate
                    }
                }
            }
            .onCompletion { emit(null) }
            .first()
}
```

Note the absence of any custom dispatchers, you don't need them for suspendable work. Any dispatcher will do, and all the work can run in a single thread.

The `onCompletion` parts steps into action when your all URL shorteners fail. In that case the `flatMapMerge` stage doesn't emit anything and `first()` would deadlock without the extra `null` injected into the flow.

To test it I used the following code:

```
class Shortener(
        private val delay: Long
) : UrlShortener {
    override suspend fun getShortUrl(longUrl: String): String? {
        delay(delay * 1000)
        println("Shortener $delay completing")
        if (delay == 1L) {
            throw Exception("failed service")
        }
        if (delay == 2L) {
            return null
        }
        return "shortened after $delay seconds"
    }
}

suspend fun main() {
    val shorteners = listOf(
            Shortener(4),
            Shortener(3),
            Shortener(2),
            Shortener(1)
    )
    measureTimeMillis {
        UrlShortenerService(shorteners).getShortUrl("bla").also {
            println(it)
        }
    }.also {
        println("Took $it ms")
    }
}
```

This exercises the various failure cases like returning null or failing with an exception. For this code I get the following output:

```
Shortener 1 completing
Shortener 2 completing
Shortener 3 completing
shortened after 3 seconds
Took 3080 ms
```

We can see that the shorteners 1 and 2 completed but with a failure, shortener 3 returned a valid response, and shortener 4 was cancelled before completing. I think this matches the requirements.

---

If you can't move away from blocking requests, your implementation will have to start `num_impls * num_concurrent_requests` threads, which is not great. However, if that's the best you can have, here's an implementation that hedges blocking requests but awaits on them suspendably and cancellably. It will send an interrupt signal to the worker threads running the requests, but if your library's IO code is non-interruptible, these threads will hang waiting for their requests to complete or time out.

```
val es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

interface UrlShortener {
    fun getShortUrl(longUrl: String): String? // not suspendable!
}

class UrlShortenerService(
        private val impls: List<UrlShortener>
) {
    suspend fun getShortUrl(longUrl: String): String {
        val chan = Channel<String?>()
        val futures = impls.map { impl -> es.submit {
            try {
                impl.getShortUrl(longUrl)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                null
            }.also { runBlocking { chan.send(it) } }
        } }
        try {
            (1..impls.size).forEach { _ ->
                chan.receive()?.also { return it }
            }
            throw Exception("All services failed")
        } finally {
            chan.close()
            futures.forEach { it.cancel(true) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , your `flatMapMerge` with `.onCompletion { emit(null) }` seems not working . Because it seems it is the first returned value...  BTW , I found `ktor` natively supports coroutine. sample code here , FYI : https://github.com/smallufo/kotlinPlay/blob/master/hedging/src/test/java/hedging/HedgeTest.kt

Comment: That could be a bug in the implementation, the documentation of `onCompletion` recommends just such usage to append items to the end of the upstream flow.

Comment: Well , if `.onCompletion { emit(null) }` works as documented  , that would be the best solution IMO. (waiting Jetbrains to fix the bug).

Comment: They already [wrote a fix](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/commit/abced7920cdab2405dd7ab7c29b348c03bcd84e3#diff-8050a7c3e6c7ee7821d8ef696ff907efR217), we can expect it in the next patch release.

Comment: Good news, the [fixing PR](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/1658) is now merged.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what the `select` APi was designed to do:

```
coroutineScope {
    select {
        impls.forEach { impl ->
            async {
               impl.getShortUrl(longUrl)
            }.onAwait { it }
        }
    }
    coroutineContext[Job].cancelChildren() // Cancel any requests that are still going.
}
```

Note that this will not handle exceptions thrown by the service implementations, you will need to use a `supervisorScope` with a custom exception handler and a filtering select loop if you want to actually handle those.

Comment: It seems your code doesn't compile... `impl.getShortUrl(longUrl)` returns `String?` , and the `select` type becomes `select<String?>` , but method should return `String`. and `coroutineContext[Job].cancelChildren()` makes the block return `Unit`  ... Mmm .... can you provide a full method ? Thanks.

Comment: I played with this approach, but it isn't worth it, the complexity ends up worse than communicating over a single channel. Treatment of failures is ugly, the filtering select loop is complex and so on.