# Is it possible to make several parallel calls and accept the first one that returns using Kotlin Flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Basically I have to make a network request using `OkHttp` in parallel to various addresses. I only care about the result of the first one that succeeds. Can I do this with `Flow` on `Kotlin`?

I've been looking around but I'm struggling with getting the requests to run in parallel, the always run in sequence.

The code basically takes a list of addresses and should return the only address that worked or null if none worked.

Thanks.

Edit: I should mention I plan on using this on Android. I can probably do it with RX but wanted to learn `Flow`. Also trying to limit the libraries I add to the app.

Edit: I have marked an answer as correct however that isn't how I did but it took me very close to how I did it but since I'm new to `Flow` I have no idea if how I did it is correct though I'm pretty sure it works after my testing.

I have a function that throws `NoSuchElementException` when not found. It calls `searchForIPAsync` which is a `suspend` function that does all the `OkHttp` work and returns `true|false`.

```
@Throws(NoSuchElementException::class)
private suspend fun findWorkingIP(ipsToTest: MutableList<String>): String? = ipsToTest
        .asFlow()
        .flatMapMerge(ipsToTest.size)
        { impl ->
            flow<String?> {
                val res = connectionHelper.searchForIPAsync(getURLToTest(impl))
                if (res) {
                    emit(impl)
                } else {
                }
            }
        }.first()
```

Then I call this and catch the exception in case nothing is found:

```
        try {
            val ipFound = findWorkingIP(ipsToTest)
            Log.w(TAG, "find: Got something " + ipFound);
            return ipFound
        } catch (ex: NoSuchElementException) {
            Log.w(TAG, "find: not found");
        }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58748645/1103872) answer your question? Keep in mind that the current version of Kotlin has a [bug](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1654) that currently makes it unreliable. They already have a patch so I assume it will be fixed in the next patch release.

Comment: Thanks, this does look pretty similar, I have to see if I can figure out a way to do it with `OkHttp`.

Comment: You sure can, the answer contains variants for both blocking and non-blocking calls. In the edit history there's also a variant that doesn't use `Flow` and so avoids the mentioned bug.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it working, but since I'm new to `Flow` no idea if I'm doing it right. Copying what I saw on that post, I removed the call to `onCompletion` as it seems to have a bug though what I saw is different, whatever I emit on `onCompletion` is what goes into `first()` regardless of other `emit`s. So since I removed that I had to `try..catch` the entire thing for `NoSuchElementException` for whenever nothing works. If you want to make an answer I will mark it as correct or I can make one. Just a little hesitant since I don't know if it is right or just a hackish way.

Comment: `what I saw is different, whatever I emit on onCompletion is what goes into first() regardless of other emits` -- this is exactly what the reported bug is about. I think your solution with `NoSuchElementException` is pretty good too.

Comment: Ok cool, I guess I misread the bug and found an alternate way, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the Flow-based solution in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58748645/1103872) is a close match to what you need, unfortunately as of Kotlin 1.3.2 the Flow implementation has a [bug](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1654) that breaks it. The bug already has a proposed fix so this should be resolved with the next patch release of Kotlin. In the meantime, here's a similar solution that uses `async` and `Channel` instead:

```
suspend fun getShortUrl(urls: List<String>): String = coroutineScope {
    val chan = Channel<String?>()
    urls.forEach { url ->
        launch {
            try {
                fetchUrl(url)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                null
            }.also { chan.send(it) }
        }
    }
    try {
        (1..urls.size).forEach { _ ->
            chan.receive()?.also { return@coroutineScope it }
        }
        throw Exception("All services failed")
    } finally {
        coroutineContext[Job]!!.cancelChildren()
    }
}
```

Comment: I added to the bottom of the post the way I did it, thank you for the help.